# Translate Devise Login links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I use this link to put the login links on my application :

```
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-sign_in,-sign_out,-and-sign_up-links-to-your-layout-template
```

I also add a translation file for french :

```
https://gist.github.com/871074
```

And i ask rails to use french as default :

```
 config.before_configuration do
   I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
   I18n.locale = :fr
   I18n.default_locale = :fr
   config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
   config.i18n.locale = :fr
   # bypasses rails bug with i18n in production\
   I18n.reload!
   config.i18n.reload!
end

config.i18n.locale = :fr
config.i18n.default_locale = :fr
```

But for my buttons/labels are not translated :

```
<div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
```

It write "Remember me" but i want the french translation.

What did i do wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In rails 3, you will need it in the following structure:

```
fr:
  helpers:
    label:
      user:
        remember_me: French text here!
```

This [blog post](http://fredwu.me/post/434076573/rails-tip-making-i18n-forms-the-easy-way) and [this one](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2010/02/rails-3-i18n-changes/) should be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

In addition, you can add the following lines:

```
fr:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        remember_me: text
```