# translating Devise through locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 4, and Devise gem to create `User` model. simple stuff. though, when it comes to translation i have certain issues, remain in english, even though i copy solutions from [devise wiki](https://gist.github.com/Nowaker/1958933). On the other hand i know basics are correct, because alerts usin while being `logged in/out` work like a charm. Right now i'm trying to translate `'remember me' checkbox`, this one just under `Email&Password` fields, but i'm also very far from `sign-in` button etc...

here's what i've been trying, basically the same whats in devise wiki:

```
pl:
  devise:
    remember_me: "Zapamiętaj mnie" #### Not working:(
    sessions:
      user:
        signed_in: "Witaj ponownie"   #### Working hoorray!
        signed_out: "Wylogowałeś się. Zapraszamy ponownie!" ### Working hoorray!
```

EDIT

Im using devise (3.0.3)

devise.pl.yml is in locales folder

my default locale is set to :pl

Comment: What version of Devise are you using? Where are you placing this locale file? Are you setting the default locale in you application.rb?

Comment: Check [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869510/translate-devise-login-links)

Comment: just updated my question

Comment: ok, remember me, works, what do i do with the rest, sign_in button etc..?

Comment: You can read more about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451318/rails3-devise-internationalization-does-not-localize-password-confirmation-an)

Comment: You should install devise-i18n gem. As in here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/I18n

Answer (score 0):

Your view have to use the values from de dictionary of your language, please verify it